# Clumped fill categories within ggplot2 pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am attempting to make a pie chart within ggplot2, which includes a list of fish families and the quantities in which they have been exported. I have created a pie chart, but the families which I plan on being outside of the pie chart are clumped and I cannot seem to find a solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx9LD.png)

I am hoping to resolve this issue by plotting the families alongside the correct inforation. One example being that Pomacentridae should be next to the slice that is 19,056.

Here is my code

```
 library(ggrepel)
 library(tidyverse)
 library(forcats)
 library(ggplot2)

 df3 <- Family_Quantities3 %>% 
     mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(Quantities))), 
     pos = Quantities/2 + lead(csum, 1),
     pos = if_else(is.na(pos), Quantities/2, pos))

 plot15 <- ggplot(Family_Quantities3, aes(x = "", y = Quantities, fill = fct_inorder(Families)))+
    geom_col(width = 0.8, color = 1) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = Quantities),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y") +
     guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Families")) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = df3$pos, labels = Family_Quantities3$Families) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 15), 
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) 

    plot15
```

Comment: Why can't you use a legend rather than `geom_text_repel`?

Comment: I could, but the legend consists of 65 families, therefore it is quite clumped. Geom_text_repel is for the numerical values that are plotted onto the pie chart. Guides and scale_y_continous are for the values outside the main body of the graph. df3 is for the setting up of the non-numeric values, so issues may lie there but im unsure

Comment: Any plot with 65 categories is going to be cluttered!  Perhaps group the families "outside" the plot as "Other"?  Or present a higher level overview (Order?) and then drill down (Family within order)?  Without usable data, it's difficult to offer concrete advice...

Comment: I think that is a valid point. Im not sure if youd be able to recommend a way for me to remove values below a certain threshold appearing on top of the pie chart slices? From that i would do as you recommended and implement a legend

Comment: Please define what you mean by "remove values below a certain threshold appearing on top of the pie chart slices" and _provide some test data to work with_!

Comment: I have values that range from 1 to 19056, due to the extremely small points of data from families it makes more sense to not have their numerical value stated but instead just thier family name. I am unsure of how to provide said dummy data on here. Sorry I am new here

Comment: | Families| Quantities |
| -------- | -------- |
| Pomacentridae | 19056  |
| Gobiidae  | 8000
|Labridae | 7990 |
| Labrisomidae| 3  |
| Zanclidae| 277   |                                      I have attempted to create a table. I hope this helps